# Chromecast Discovery with MediaRouter too many callbacks called

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

What I have noticed is that after coming to foreground in my application I get three callbacks:

```
onRouteAdded -> onRouteRemoved -> onRouteAdded
```

First I thought there was a problem with my application, but then I tried with this sample:
https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android

And observed the logs:

> 04-30 12:08:49.940: E/TEST(857): onRouteAdded:
>   info=MediaRouter.RouteInfo{
>   uniqueId=com.google.android.gms:0246381b5bc93e0d714f6c1f73af5625,
>   name=BraKrePet, description=Chromecast, enabled=true,
>   connecting=false, playbackType=1, playbackStream=-1, volumeHandling=0,
>   volume=0, volumeMax=20, presentationDisplayId=-1,
>   extras=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=568],
>   providerPackageName=com.google.android.gms }
>
> 04-30 12:08:49.970: E/TEST(857): onRouteRemoved:
>   info=MediaRouter.RouteInfo{
>   uniqueId=com.google.android.gms:0246381b5bc93e0d714f6c1f73af5625,
>   name=BraKrePet, description=Chromecast, enabled=true,
>   connecting=false, playbackType=1, playbackStream=-1, volumeHandling=0,
>   volume=0, volumeMax=20, presentationDisplayId=-1,
>   extras=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=568],
>   providerPackageName=com.google.android.gms }
>
> 04-30 12:08:50.430: E/TEST(857): onRouteAdded:
>   info=MediaRouter.RouteInfo{
>   uniqueId=com.google.android.gms:0246381b5bc93e0d714f6c1f73af5625,
>   name=BraKrePet, description=Chromecast, enabled=true,
>   connecting=false, playbackType=1, playbackStream=-1, volumeHandling=0,
>   volume=0, volumeMax=20, presentationDisplayId=-1,
>   extras=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=568],
>   providerPackageName=com.google.android.gms }

As you can see, it is also happening there. It is causing problems in my application because my chromecast button is

```
shown -> hidden -> shown
```

Anybody have an idea as to why this is happening and what should be done to avoid it?

Comment: Is this keep happening over and over? Can you try that on a different network and see if the same thing happens there as well or not?

Comment: Yeah, it does. The strange thing Is that it only happens if my app is the only app running chromecast. If both my app and the app from Github are running, I only get one callback and everything works fine.

Comment: Did you try that on a different network? Enable logging for Play Services to see more

Comment: We are also seeing this... how do we go about enabling logging for Play Services?